# can I show custom title in Firebase Crashlytics when I record the error manually?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, crashlytics

in my Firebase Crashlytics console, the display will be like this

[image]

I try to record the error using the code below

```
      FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(
        error,
        null, // I pass null for stackTrace argument in here
        reason: "Failed to create cart, createChildList method failed to be executed on cart.dart file.",
        fatal: false,
      );
```

the problem is .....

all error recorded using the code above will be displayed as `firebase_crashlytics.dart - line 117`

it is not descriptive enough. Could I possibly show the dart file name instead? like in the second and third row in the image above?

I suspect it is because I pass `null` on the `stackTrace` argument when I recording the error. the problem is, I am confused how to create stackTrace object to be passed on the `recordError` method

can I show custom title in Firebase Crashlytics when I record the error 'manually' like that ?

Answer (score 2):

yup, to show the error title in Crashlytics console, I have to pass the stack trace.

if you wanna show your page/screen name or dart file name, then you can pass the stackTrace like this

```
      FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(
        Exception("your exception message"),
        StackTrace.current, // you should pass stackTrace in here
        reason: "Error reason",
        fatal: false,
      );
```

Comment: No. There is no such API. The only API is: `public void recordException(@NonNull Throwable throwable)`

Comment: @MichałDobiDobrzański you are right, we can't create super custom title, my answer above is at least so we can track the file name where the problem occured instead of 'firebase_crashlytics.dart'